# SystemError: PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN macro must be defined for '#' formats

Tags: python, pycrypto

I cannot find anything on this. I'm getting error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/pwdb.py", line 265, in <module>
    password_db()
  File "/path/to/pwdb.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.cipher = AES.new(key,AES.MODE_ECB)
  File "/home/STACKOVERFLOW/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/AES.py", line 95, in new
    return AESCipher(key, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/STACKOVERFLOW/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/AES.py", line 59, in __init__
    blockalgo.BlockAlgo.__init__(self, _AES, key, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/STACKOVERFLOW/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/blockalgo.py", line 141, in __init__
    self._cipher = factory.new(key, *args, **kwargs)
SystemError: PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN macro must be defined for '#' formats
```

I'm pretty sure the line it's getting the error from is:

```py
self.cipher = AES.new(key,AES.MODE_ECB)
```

The script was working not too long ago. Did PyCrypto update its formatting or something ? And does anyone have any idea on how to fix this ? I can provide more of the code if need be.

Answer (score 24):

**uninstall pycryto and install pycryptodome**

```
pip uninstall pycrypto
pip install pycryptodome
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: pycrypto is no longer maintained: see https://www.pycrypto.org/

pycryptodome is the modern maintained replacement for pycrypto

Comment: Downvoted because: No explanation and didn’t change anything on my system.

Comment: ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'pycrypto'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

Answer (score 17):

It sounds like the extension was not updated for python 3.10.

On 3.10 any module(s) that use the `#` variant when parsing arguments need to have a `#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN` before including Python.h.

From the docs:

> For all # variants of formats (s#, y#, etc.), the macro
> PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN must be defined before including Python.h. On Python
> 3.9 and older, the type of the length argument is Py_ssize_t if the PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN macro is defined, or int otherwise.

See https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html#strings-and-buffers

Comment: what value should I set PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN?

Comment: If you add `#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN`, you should also go through all formats containing `s#`, etc., and make sure the length argument is a `Py_ssize_t`, not `int`.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [pycryptodome](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) python package instead of pycrypto. Pycryptodome seems to have replaced the currently not maintained pycrypto package and works as is with the python 3.10 related changes as well.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31793428)

Answer (score 1):

I might have fixed it for AES, pretty sure I fixed it for RIPEMD160, as my `slotmachine` code is now running on termux, and it wasn't before. The code changes are at https://github.com/jcomeauictx/pycrypto/commit/38e5ebbf98fea96cf67b354e13fef7d1959ec34a, and you can install it using `pip install git+https://github.com/jcomeauictx/pycrypto`. Note that I haven't made any attempt to fix any security issues in the pycrypto code, I only addressed this `PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN` problem.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error trying to run `bsdiff4` with python 3.10, installed using `conda`.

Turns out `conda` has an old version of `bsdiff4` (1.1.5).

Uninstalling the `conda` version of `bsdiff4` and re-installing the latest (1.2.4) using `pip` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, python was updated on my environment, and pycrypto seemed not to work with it.

**It worked with the python 3.9.18 installed in my Virtual Env.**

Check the python version you are working with and change it.

If you are using Visual Studio you can check on the bottom-right corner.

[image: python version seen on visual studio footer]